# Codeigniter form validation using bootstrap tab views

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, validation

Probably something obvious that I fail to see where it goes wrong. Perhaps its the logic I misunderstand. I searched quite a lot and everything I found only dealt with navigation problems for selecting the proper tabs.

I have a rather large site developed using PHP on platform codeigniter v2.2.3. It uses FORMS, FORM validation and ocassionally some jQuery (mainly for visualisation). So I know how the Model, Controller, View system works even as Form validation and display of errors, refilling forms etc.

**The problem:** I have a backend where some controllers provide me data on several topics and allow me to make changes using simple PHP/CI forms. I want to integrate these various controllers that are now started from a switchboard/one page into one page with TABS. So I can use tabbed views. Mainly one tab linked to one controller.

I can display the tabs, fill it with data from a controller/view. I can also show a form on a tab when selected. **However:** when I submit the form, my view breaks out of the TABBED view. The same when errors are generated. I don't want to recode all logic of validation over to jquery. The site is simply too large.

**Question:** I am looking how to properly display the **reopened** form when there were form validation errors...

[screendump of tabs with form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PDrb.png)

Below the "logic". The complete code (an isolated username, email example) can be found at my public bitbucket repo: https://bitbucket.org/ALchEmiXt/ci-tab-test

**Building the tabs:**

Initial controller testtab:

```
<?php
class Testtab extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {
        $this->data['welcome'] = 'Welcome tester!';
        $this->load->view( 'testtab_view', $this->data );
    }
}
?>
```

Initial view testtab_view: (footer and header load all default generic jquery, bootstrap logic)

```
<?php $this->load->view('header_testform'); ?>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="uvpbTabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#form1" data-tab-url="testform">formtesting</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#stats">Stats</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#admin">Admin</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The data and views come here -->       
<div class="tab-content" id="all-tabs">

    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active"><h3><?php echo $welcome ?></h3></div>

    <div id="form1" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
    <div id="stats" class="tab-pane fade"><h3>Stats of the pages</h3></div>
    <div id="admin" class="tab-pane fade"><h3>Admin stuff</h3></div>

</div>

<?php $this->load->view('footer_testform'); ?>
```

**The form**

testform controller:

```
<?php
class Testform extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('testtabform_view');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('testform_succes');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

testtabform_view

```
<div id="formcontainer">
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

    <?php echo form_open('testform'); ?>

    <h3>TestTabForm_view</h3>

    <h5>Username</h5>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />

    <h5>Email Address</h5>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="50" />

    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
}
//  $this->load->view('testtabform_view');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('validation_errors', validation_errors());
    redirect('testtab');
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('testform_succes');
}
```

Then control `$this->session->flashdata('validation_errors');` checking if those are set.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Seems I miss exactly what to do with your last sentence. I keep ending up either in a reloading loop on the form or have the same tabset shown twice. If I check on errors in testform controller to either show the view or to redirect It shows correctly but with the same problem as my question. Ideas?